# How to solve this one dimensional motion question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image]

I was able to deduce the following information from the problem:

acceleration of police = 2m/s^2

x0 = 50 meters

t= 5 seconds

final velocity = 0 m/s

However, I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Use the SUVAT equation $s = ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2$. You are given $u$ and $a$ for both the motorist and the policeman so you can calculate $s$ as a function of time for both.

Comment: That gives me an equation of 50 = (1o)t + t^2. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sometimes easier, particularly when first using the constant acceleration kinematic equations, to draw velocity vs time graphs for the motions.

[image]

The area under a velocity against time graphs gives you the displacement, so use the graphs and equate the area.
When you do this you should see the kinematic equations appearing within your solution.
There is also an advantage that having got an answer for the time the graph can be used to check whether the answer which has been achieved is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem is to recognise that the trooper will catch the motorist when their respective distances are equal. So, you need to express their distances in terms of the known quantities, and equate them to find the unknowns.

Note that you have forgotten one of your known quantities (the velocity of the motorist), and you have made an erroneous assumption with another. When doing this type of calculation, you should only consider the timeframe which is relevant to the situation. In this case, you should only consider the time from when the motorist passes the trooper to the instant the trooper reaches the motorist again.

Comment: I did what you said and got the following equation:

Δx = 10t+ 0.5(2t^2)


But I don't know the value of Δx. So how can I solve this equation?

Comment: You should, in fact, begin with two different expressions for distance: one for the motorist and one for the trooper. The initial velocity of the motorist should not be confused with the acceleration of the trooper, as you have done above. Once you have an expression for each: $Δx_1 = ...$ and $Δx_2 = ...$ you equate the two together, ridding of your unknown $Δx$. After that, you can apply the value of $t$ to one of the relationships that you have to find $Δx$.

Comment: Importantly, the formulae that you are using only apply to constant linear motion.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a bit too long for a comment I put is as an answer.

If you take $x_0$ and $t$ you extracted and put it in some equation of motion, you will get something, but not what you want.
I will try to answer your conceptual problems:

- You have to figure out the equation of motion for the motorist (constant $V$) and the cop (accelerated motion)
- $x_0$ is typically the x axis offset. When you say your cop starts at $x=0$ and then look at the movement of motorist you will have to ask yourself: "How far has the motorist traveled away from the cop when the cops starts the case?"